# ¿Existe un modo de automatizar el versionado de las SPI?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

Me gustaría saber si existe un modo de automatizar el incremento de las versiones de las SPI luego del deploy.
He encontrado algunas opciones pero específicamente para API o para reversionar proyectos luego del build; más no he encontrado documentación exclusivamente para reversionar las SPI de modo automático luego del deployment.
¿Podrían indicarme alguna documentación para interiorizarme en el tema? o si la pregunta ya fue formulada, si pueden redirigirme a ella.

Answer (score 0):

Paso a dejar una posible solución que estoy investigando para resolver mi propia pregunta. Una opción aparentemente viable es utilizando Git y GitHub, creando un hook post-commit  que contenga un script de incremento de versión.

Los pasos a seguir serían los siguientes:

1. Crea un archivo de control de versiones en el proyecto, en el cual se mantendrá el número de versión actual. Es posible utilizar un archivo de texto plano, un archivo XML o cualquier otro formato que resulte cómodo.
2. Crea un script que se encargue de incrementar el número de versión en el archivo de control de versiones cada vez que se realice un deploy, en el lenguaje que resulte más cómodo.

Ejemplo:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        // Obtener la ruta del archivo de control de versiones
        string versionFilePath = "ruta/al/archivo/version.txt";

        // Leer la versión actual del archivo
        string currentVersion = File.ReadAllText(versionFilePath);

        // Parsear la versión actual en un arreglo de números
        int[] versionNumbers = Array.ConvertAll(currentVersion.Split('.'), int.Parse);

        // Incrementar el número de versión de la forma "X.Y.Z"
        versionNumbers[2]++;

        // Actualizar la versión a "X.Y.Z+1"
        string newVersion = string.Join(".", versionNumbers);
        File.WriteAllText(versionFilePath, newVersion);

        // Realizar el deploy aquí...
    }
}
```

3. Crea un hook post-commit en Git que se encargue de ejecutar el script de incremento de versión cada vez que se realice un commit en el repositorio. Para ello, hay que crear un archivo llamado "post-commit" en la carpeta ".git/hooks" del repositorio del proyecto y escribir en él el comando que ejecuta el script.
4. Agrega y haz commit del archivo de control de versiones al repositorio. Este archivo debe ser parte del repositorio para que el hook post-commit pueda ejecutar el script de incremento de versión.
5. Realiza el deploy y confirmar que funciona correctamente el versionado.